# Can I pass a local variable in a jpa.repository.Query

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Мy question is the following:

I have this method in my VisitsRepository

```
    @Query("SELECT s FROM DoctorVisits s WHERE s.patient.id=")
    List<DoctorVisits> findPatientById(long id);
```

I would like to know how I can pass the id parameter in the query above?

Comment: Change `long id` to `@Param("id") long id` and then replace `WHERE s.patient.id=` with `WHERE s.patient.id=:id`

Comment: as @Lino says or `SELECT s FROM DoctorVisits s WHERE s.patient.id=?1` where '?1' is the first parameter, ?2 the second,...